# FireFox gives NS_ERROR_FAILURE on an Ajax Call in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, firefox

I am calling a web service by jsp page via ajax call below is my code of calling.

```
var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            //treat Response
            plotGraphs(xmlhttp.responseText, url, port);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open('GET',url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Now the problem is that the above code works perfect on Chrome but gives NS_ERROR_FAILURE in Firefox. The full error is `Exception... "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"`. I tried to make all different object for xmlhttp but it won't work. Please suggest WHAT other can I try to resolve it?